# How to add new line to ListView Builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have ListView Builder widget and it has pictures. When user click add button , it adds a picture to ListView. It is a card game. I want ListView builder horizontally but its overflow. I dont want that.

I want ListView Builder dont overflow. I want new line for listview Builder.

[image]

Heres my code :

```
Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    colour: Colors.green,
                    cardChild: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: cardBrain.mycards.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) => Image(
                        height: 10,
                        width: 55,
                        image: AssetImage(
                          '${cardBrain.mycards[i].image}',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),)
```

Comment: You want new line or not overflow?

Comment: I want new line

Comment: After add button clicked, add a new line?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `gridView.builder`
when you added a item to list then call setState